# Some R packages won't install

Tags: package-management, compiling, r

I have R version 3.4.2, trying to install `ggplot2`, ran `install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)` in RStudio.  It eventually tells me it exited with non-zero exit status and the errors are hard to read because the message is so long, but I see that in the process `Matrix` was a dependency which also failed to install, so I try to directly install that, and here's what I see in the error message for that:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'Matrix.so' failed
make: *** [Matrix.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Matrix’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Matrix’
```

I'm not clear on what `ld` is at all and if I need to research that to solve this problem.  It looks like it might alternately have something to do with `Matrix.so`.

Comment: You should not install R-packages system-wide. User per-user folders instead.

Comment: @user68186: The answers to the linked duplicate question recommend the installation of `r-base-dev` among others. This package depends on the packages that provide the development files for the missing libraries. It's a duplicate indeed.

Comment: Make sure that package is using g++ or gcc and have the same version of fortran installed.
`gcc --version` `g++ --version` and `gfortran --version`
`sudo apt install gfortran-8` My package used gcc. I have version 8.4.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install these build-dependencies for R-package:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

And then install R-packages to your home folder (that is `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library`). You do not need to run RStudio as *root*.

Comment: I installed `r-base-dev` and opened RStudio, then used `install.packages` and it works!  Thanks!  I wasn't really clear on how to install the packages to my home folder--I don't see a destination option.  But I'm guessing it does this by default?  Anyway, since it worked, I'm guessing it's fine.